# AIR - Supress Error messages in debug app?

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, error-handling, air

In a packaged AIR app, I need to add a file called `debug` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\The App\META-INF\AIR\debug` for the software to function 'correctly' - I think it is a database error but I can not find anyway to solve it at the moment.

Is it possible to add this debug flag, but to suppress/hide any modal error boxes that may appear from another possible yet unknown bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand your problem. If what you need is some specific behavior only happening when you run the app in debug mode, then take a look to conditional compilation for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736411/flash-flex-conditional-compilation-else).

But again, unsure I fully understand your problem!