# Negating directives

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a boolean compiler directive

```
-define=CONFIG::dev,true
```

I'd like to know if there is some manner of negate that value. Example:

```
CONFIG:dev{
    // the code if dev is true
}

!CONFIG:dev{
    // the code if dev is false
}
```

Comment: see at this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736411/flash-flex-conditional-compilation-else